# codeigniter helper function did not loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to "rebuild" again my web project in Codeigniter, but I totally forgot how to setting it..
In the last 3 years, this website contains no error and all works great. but when I try to reopen again, it contains errors like this :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function admin_info() in C:\xampp\htdocs\misnews\application\controllers\home.php on line 27

PS : the `admin_info()` functions are inside the helper, and I loaded it in autoload and added `$this->load->helper('basic_helper);` in the home controller

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your helper is named basic_helper.php

**application / helpers / basic_helper.php**

Then all you should need to do is `$this->load->helper('basic');`

You can also autoload helper in

**application / config / autoload.php**

When you need to use helper `$this->basic->some_function();`